# FileOutputStream switching between appending and overwriting

Tags: java, file-io, fileoutputstream

I have made a simple data file which contains a header of only 4 bytes. These 4 bytes define how many records are stored inside the file. Both the header and record are of pre-defined sizes and cannot vary.

EDIT: Also the record only contains 4 bytes aswell. Which define just an integer number.
The LINE_SEPERATOR = byte { '\r', '\n' }

My problem is that each time I add a new record (append) I need to overwrite the header (not appending) becouse the record count should be increased by one. However the program refuses to switch between them and it just sticks with the non append mode.

addRecord code:

```
public void addRecord(ISaveable record)
        throws IllegalArgumentException, FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    if(record == null)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The given record may not be null");
    }

    this.header.increaseRecordCount();

    writeHeader();

    FileOutputStream oStream = null;
    try
    {
        oStream = new FileOutputStream(DEFAULT_DIR, true);

        long offset = calculateOffset(this.header.getRecordCount() - 1, record.getSize());

        System.out.println("writing record @ " + offset);
        oStream.getChannel().position(offset);

        PacketOutputStream pOut = new PacketOutputStream();
        record.Save(pOut);
        pOut.writeBytes(END_LINE);
        oStream.write(pOut.Seal());
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        if(oStream != null)
        {
            oStream.flush();
            oStream.close();
        }
    } 
}
```

The writeHeader code:

```
private void writeHeader()
        throws IOException
{
    FileOutputStream oStream = null;
    try
    {
        oStream = new FileOutputStream(DEFAULT_DIR, false);

        oStream.getChannel().position(0);

        PacketOutputStream pOut = new PacketOutputStream();

        this.header.Save(pOut);
        pOut.writeBytes(END_LINE);

        oStream.write(pOut.Seal());
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        if(oStream != null)
        {
            oStream.flush();
            oStream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I am using the booleans in the constructor of FileOutputStream correctly. Giving the writeHeader a false (becouse I want to overwrite the existing header) and the record a true (becouse it should be added to the end of the file). Please ignore the fact that setting append to true that it will automaticly seek to the end. The calculateOffset method is for future implementations.

I have done experiments where I only write the header everytime. It works perfectly when set to not append. And as expected when it's set to append it will add multiple headers.

The result I'm getting from my file right now after trying to add 4 records is only 2 lines. The header is perfect, there's nothing wrong with it. However all 4 records are written on the next line overwriting eachother.

The resulting debug text:

1. writing record @ 6
2. writing record @ 12
3. writing record @ 18
4. writing record @ 24
5. reading record @ 6
6. 3457

All record positions are correct, however the '3457' is the result of all 4 records overwritten on the same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write to multiple points in a file, you should really consider using [`RandomAccessFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html), which was designed for this purpose.

Update: You should also use the same `RandomAccessFile` instance for all writes instead of creating one separately every time you update the header or the contents.

Comment: Thanks alot! That did exactly what I wanted.